# Array of objects as a field in a class. How to access parameters of single object?

Tags: arrays, ruby, object

I started yesterday with Ruby and have a problem.
I have two classes: Patient and Patient_history.
Patient can have multiple histories (from different appointments).

Here is what i have now:

```
class Patient
    attr_accessor :name,
                  :surname,
                  :histories

def initialize(*)
  @histories = []
end

def create_patient
  @name = create_name_or_surname( "name")
  @surname = create_name_or_surname("surname")
end

def create_name_or_surname( name_or_surname)
  #not relevant in this case
end

def add_history(history)
  @histories.push(history)
end

def print_patient
  puts "name: #{@name}"
  puts "surname : #{@surname}"

  ## I wish to do sth like:
  ## puts "history date: #{@histories[1].date}"
  ## to print content of Patient_history

end
end
```

And

```
class Patient_history
   attr_accessor :date,
                 :description

  def create_history
    @date = create_date_or_desc("What is the date today?")
    @description = create_date_or_desc("Write about an illness:")
  end
end
```

with a line:
p patient
after setting history and patient values i get:

```
What is your name?
john
What is your surname?
smith
What is the date today?
12/12/2016
Write about an illness:
sick
#<Patient:0x007ffcb50ab518 @histories=[#
<Patient_history:0x007ffcb50aad98 @date="12/12/2016", 
@description="sick">], @name="john", @surname="smith">
```

Can you give me a hint of what to do?

Comment: Note: It should be `initialize` not `initialize(*)`.

Comment: So  your `p patient` looks good... I can see the patient record, and that it contains a array of histories.  What do you want it to do now?

Comment: What to do to do what?

Comment: I wish to get to that patient_history object from Patient so I can print out Patient and the history from a method def print_patient.

I commented out in that method what was my intentions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is a little vague, do you wish to print out the list of patient histories? You can iterate over each history using [#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each).

```
def print_patient
  puts "name: #{@name}"
  puts "surname : #{@surname}"

  histories.each do |history|
    puts "History Date: #{history.date}"
    puts history.description
  end
end
```